# Linq Basic Query

Tags: linq

I have a very basic question in linq. I have below classes.

```
    public class PostUser
    {
        int UserId {get;set;}
        string Username {get;set;}
        string Email {get;set;}
        IList<Post> Posts {get;set;}
    }

   public class Post
   {
        int PostId {get;set;}
        int ThreadId {get;set;}
        int UserId {get;set;}
        string PageText {get;set;}
        string IPAddress {get;set;}
   }
```

I want to get all the PostUser where Post having IPAdress=10.5.23.132

Thanks

Comment: It´s important to show your effort in order that people help you! We are not here to do your homeworks ;)

Comment: PostUser.Where(x=>x.Post.Where(y=>y.IPAddress=="10.5.23.132")). I believe this should work, but it giving me an error saying "cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<Post> to bool"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then if you have a list of PostUser, try something like:

```
var result = postUser.Where(x => x.Posts.Any(y => y.IPAddress == "10.5.23.132"));
```